# Creating user accounts for pre-registered users in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a website that has a registration system and a blog with some registered users. Yesterday, I added a new app that creates dedicated profile pages for each one of those users.

The issue being, the profile pages aren't getting created for the users that have already registered. This is, I guess because the user profile creation logic allows for profile creations only after the user has registered.

Below is the code in my ***models.py***

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_account(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, new = UserAccount.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_account, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

So, what can I do to create those profile pages?

I tried the following:
1. Manually creating a profile page against each registered users' username. (But this isn't the way I want to lean on. This is just a temporary arrangement)

Issue with this, when the superuser who creates these profile pages calls for his private profile page [at /u/], the code looks towards all the users created by the superuser instead of his own.

This is the error that's shown:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /u/

get() returned more than one UserAccount -- it returned 2!

.
.
.
instance = get_object_or_404(UserAccount)
```

So, what's the issue in code here? [my views.py]

```
# public user profile
def user_account(request, username):
    instance = get_object_or_404(UserAccount, user__username=username)
    context = {
    'instance'  : instance,
    'title'     : "User Account",       
    }
    template = "user_accounts/public_account.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

# private user profile.
@login_required
def self_user_account(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Http404

    instance = get_object_or_404(UserAccount)

    if not request.user == instance.user:
        raise Http404

    context = {
        'instance'  : instance,
        'title'     : 'Your Account',
    }   

    template = "user_accounts/self_account.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

# ability to update the user profile
@login_required
def update_user_account(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Http404

    instance = get_object_or_404(UserAccount)

    if not request.user == instance.user:
        raise Http404

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserAccountForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, "Account Updated.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/u/")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Something went wrong. Profile not created.")
    else:
        form = UserAccountForm(instance=instance)

    context = {
        'title': 'Update Your Account',
        'form' : form,
    }
    template = "user_accounts/update.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Below is my ***urls.py*** These are populated after /u/ from the main ***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    # for updating
    url(r'^update/$', views.update_user_account, name="update_user_account"),
    # for outside world
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', views.user_account, name="public_user_account"),
    # for the user himself 
    url(r'^$', views.self_user_account, name="self_user_account"),
]
```

Below is my ***models.py*** script

```
# uploading profile photos
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "account_photos/%s/%s" %(instance.user, filename)

# Create your models here.
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo           = models.ImageField(
                        upload_to=upload_location, # there needs to be a upload location tho
                        # most probably a cdn server
                        blank=True,
                        null=True, 
                        width_field="width_field",
                        height_field="height_field")
    width_field     = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    height_field    = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    bio             = models.TextField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="You in 60 words.")
    phone           = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, verbose_name="Contact Number")
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="Student")
    totos           = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Contribution")
    user_since      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # social links
    email           = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email address", 
                                        max_length=255,
                                        unique=True,
                                        null=True, blank=True)
    custom_link     = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    facebook_link   = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_link    = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    linkedin_link   = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    github_link     = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    reddit_link     = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.reverse("accounts:public_user_account", kwargs={"username":self.user__username})

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User) # User is coming from the user=models.OneToOneField(<User>)
def create_account(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, new = UserAccount.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_account, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: Please show your URL patterns, and the full traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair added. Please have a look.

Comment: You still haven't shown the full traceback. Your current error shows `instance = get_object_or_404(UserAccount)`, which isn't in the view that `/u/` uses.

Comment: Actually I'll have to 'debug=True' on a live site for that. The traceback shows the 'instance = get_object_or_404(UserAccount)' at the '/u/' i.e. in the 'self_user_account(request)' function.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the `urls.py` - I though `/u/` was testing a username `'u'`, but it's from the `include()`. So I probably don't need the full traceback in this case. As I explain in the answer below, you shouldn't use `get_object_or_404(UserAccount)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `get_object_or_404(UserAccount)` uses *all* user accounts, so it will give a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error if more than one user account exists.

You need to filter the queryset so that it only returns one object. You are already using the username to do this. This should work as long as username is unique and there is only one user account per user.

```
get_object_or_404(UserAccount, user__username=username)
```

If you want to filter on the logged in user, you can do:

```
get_object_or_404(UserAccount, user=request.user)
```

Or, depending on your models, you might be able to follow the one-to-one field backwards, for example:

```
instance = request.user.useraccount
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Alasdair. In case of `get_object_or_404(UserAccount, user=request.user)` [I've tried this hence the question] how would I pass on the extra parameter of user from the webpage?

Comment: Also, this solves the temporary issue, how can I create these accounts for the already registered users? Manually doing it would be a tiresome and a non-django task and it renders the issue that you wrote the answer about.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In the `user_account` view you already know how to filter on a parameter: `get_object_or_404(UserAccount, user__username=username)`.

Comment: You also know how to create a user account - in your signal you use `UserAccount.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)`. So if you don't want to create accounts for existing users manually, then write a script that does.

Comment: Q1: I'm getting `MultipleObjectsReturned` error. Is it doing this because I've manually added user accounts manually from the admin panel or because of the flaws in the '`views.py` script?

Comment: Q2: To create those accounts, what would I need? Any Django module that I can make use of? I mean, in psuedo-code it'd be: "if user exists and account!=created, create_account()" but how can I check that in Django? `post_save` only works after a certain user registration signal is sent to it. I can't send signals here, the users have been registered already.

Comment: There might be a problem with your models or your script. *I'm getting MultipleObjectsReturned error* isn't enough info.

Comment: adding `models.py` as well. But seriously, I'm really thankful to you for taking out time like this. [sorry]

Comment: Your `UserAccount` model has `user = models.OneToOneField(User)`, which looks OK. You don't need a Django module to create the accounts. You can use `UserAccount.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)` to create the account - it won't create the user account if it already exists. See the [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) docs for more info.

Comment: But, I'm already using `get_or_create` to create the accounts.

Comment: I'm a stupid developer. `instance=get_object_or_404(UserAccount, user=request.user)` did the trick of solving the `MultipleObjectsReturned` error.

Comment: Not stupid, but I did mention that in my answer an hour ago ;)

Comment: Yup you did. And I got messed up b/w different keywords I guess. But, thanks a lot Alasdair! Now, all that remains is the issue of creating user accounts for existing users.

Comment: It sounds like you need a script that loops through all users and calls `get_or_create()`.